# What will be the impact of MySQL transaction is not rolling back?

Tags: mysql, transactions, commit, rollback

This is the general question on MySQL. Suppose we have started a transaction in our script (Script can be of any language like Python, PHP, Nodejs, etc) and due to some validation issue in data, we need to stop the script. And we have stopped the script without rolling back the transaction.

What will be the impact on MySQL in this case?

Comment: MySQL may or may not be impacted. For a more detailed answer, we'd probably want to see a sample script

Answer (score 0):

There are really two outcomes here in absence of a transaction.  Should the database operation be interrupted, the good scenario would be either that a) the transaction had just begun and no DML had executed, or b) the transaction DML had already completed.  In this case, your underlying data would not be corrupted, but then you might not know whether or not the transaction executed.  The bad scenario would happen when the transaction were cut off in the middle of some DML.  In this case, you could have inconsistent data in your tables.

Really, the only safe way to go here is to use transactions or only execute atomic SQL statements (which, however, automatically will run inside thier own transaction).

Comment: I’m confused, I read the question as if a transaction _is_ active and the op just wants to know what happens if the script just leaves it uncommitted.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Well I might assume that the script would close/release the database connection, which in turn should also close any open transactions.  The remaining issue, then, is what happens to the underlying data on MySQL.